# How to get span text by its class?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the text in a span element. The problem is that it doesn't have an unique ID, only a class. Is there a way to retrieve the text inside this  element by knowing only its class?

I tried this code:

```
var theValue = document.getElementById('you').getElementsByClassName('username').innerHTML;
```

but I got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null

HTML:

```
<div id="you">
       <span class="username">theTextIShouldGet</span>

        <a class="logout" href="/logout">
         </a>
        <a class="settings" href="/settings">
         </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you've got is fine. If you got that error, then either the `<div>` doesn't really have that "id" value, or else the `<div>` was not in the DOM when the code ran.

Comment: Also elementsByClassName is plural. Add a [0] to get the first one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get that error because you're trying to access that element before it's loaded on the page. Move your script to the bottom of the page or wrap you script in a DOM ready function.

As for getting the text by class, sure! `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection - so you'll need to reference the index you want:

```
<div id="you">
   <span class="username">theTextIShouldGet</span>

    <a class="logout" href="/logout">
     </a>
    <a class="settings" href="/settings">
     </a>
</div>
<script>
    var theValue = document.getElementById('you').getElementsByClassName('username')[0].innerHTML;
</script>
```